# Appending a list with a dictionary key that contains multiple values from a json response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm traversing a json response in which stats are grouped by games played. I want to gather all of the values from the set and assign a single dictionary key to them. Currently every value has its own key. Here is a sample of the json response:

```
{'data': [{'ast': 9,
           'blk': 0,
           'dreb': 4,
           'fg3_pct': 0.0,
           'fg3a': 2,
           'fg3m': 0,
           'fg_pct': 0.6,
           'fga': 20,
           'fgm': 12,
           'ft_pct': 0.333,
           'fta': 3,
           'ftm': 1,
           'game': {'date': '2003-10-29T00:00:00.000Z',
                    'home_team_id': 26,
                    'home_team_score': 106,
                    'id': 15946,
                    'period': 4,
                    'postseason': False,
                    'season': 2003,
                    'status': 'Final',
                    'time': ' ',
                    'visitor_team_id': 6,
                    'visitor_team_score': 92},
           'id': 361330,
           'min': '42:50',
           'oreb': 2,
           'pf': 3,
           'player': {'first_name': 'LeBron',
                      'height_feet': 6,
                      'height_inches': 8,
                      'id': 237,
                      'last_name': 'James',
                      'position': 'F',
                      'team_id': 14,
                      'weight_pounds': 250},
           'pts': 25,
           'reb': 6,
           'stl': 4,
           'team': {'abbreviation': 'CLE',
                    'city': 'Cleveland',
                    'conference': 'East',
                    'division': 'Central',
                    'full_name': 'Cleveland Cavaliers',
                    'id': 6,
                    'name': 'Cavaliers'},
           'turnover': 2},
          {'ast': 8,
           'blk': 0,
           'dreb': 10,
           'fg3_pct': 0.2,
           'fg3a': 5,
           'fg3m': 1,
           'fg_pct': 0.471,
           'fga': 17,
           'fgm': 8,
           'ft_pct': 0.571,
           'fta': 7,
           'ftm': 4,
           'game': {'date': '2003-10-30T00:00:00.000Z',
                    'home_team_id': 24,
                    'home_team_score': 95,
                    'id': 16277,
                    'period': 4,
                    'postseason': False,
                    'season': 2003,
                    'status': 'Final',
                    'time': ' ',
                    'visitor_team_id': 6,
                    'visitor_team_score': 86},
           'id': 361523,
           'min': '40:21',
           'oreb': 2,
           'pf': 1,
           'player': {'first_name': 'LeBron',
                      'height_feet': 6,
                      'height_inches': 8,
                      'id': 237,
                      'last_name': 'James',
                      'position': 'F',
                      'team_id': 14,
                      'weight_pounds': 250},
           'pts': 21,
           'reb': 12,
           'stl': 1,
           'team': {'abbreviation': 'CLE',
                    'city': 'Cleveland',
                    'conference': 'East',
                    'division': 'Central',
                    'full_name': 'Cleveland Cavaliers',
                    'id': 6,
                    'name': 'Cavaliers'},
           'turnover': 7},
```

This is my code:

```
    players_stats=[]
    players_game_stats_url="https://balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?season[]=2018&player_ids[]=237"
    result=requests.get(players_game_stats_url).json()

    for assists in result['data']:
        players_stats.append({"Assists per game":assists['ast']})
```

What I would like to produce is something like this:

{Assists per game:9,8,6,7,3}

But what I'm getting is this:

```
[{'Assists per game': 9},
 {'Assists per game': 8},
 {'Assists per game': 6},
 {'Assists per game': 7},
 {'Assists per game': 3},
 {'Assists per game': 9},
 {'Assists per game': 4},
 {'Assists per game': 7},
 {'Assists per game': 3},
 {'Assists per game': 8},
 {'Assists per game': 8},
 {'Assists per game': 8},
 {'Assists per game': 2},
 {'Assists per game': 4},
 {'Assists per game': 9},
 {'Assists per game': 7},
 {'Assists per game': 7},
 {'Assists per game': 5},
 {'Assists per game': 8},
 {'Assists per game': 5},
 {'Assists per game': 3},
 {'Assists per game': 9},
 {'Assists per game': 4},
 {'Assists per game': 6},
 {'Assists per game': 3}]
```

Comment: If you want to get unique values, put them in a set, then format the output afterwards. This will get the result you specified, although the result you specified is not "assists per game".

Comment: Get the data with assists = [game['ast'] for game in results['data']] and then do your math or whatever, then format the output for display

Comment: @KennyOstrom so just create a separate set from the response and then plug it into a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based the comment from Kenny Ostrom

```py
    output = {"Assists per game": [game_info['ast'] for game_info in result['data']]}
```

which is going to result like you asked

```py
    {'Assists per game': [9, 8]}
```